# Laravel, how to check if this is the only record in a table

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to check if this is the only record in a table, so if yes then don't delete it, else delete it, what I have is just check if its the last one and this is not what Im looking for

```
    $order=EditUserorder::find($rowId);
    $last_record = EditUserorder::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();        
    if($order->id == $last_record->id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would work

```php
if(EditUserorder::count() == 1) {
    #...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if(EditUserorder::where('id', '!=', $rowId)->exists()) {
    // other records exist
    EditUserorder::find($rowId)->delete(); //delete the record
}
```

The exists method checks if any model was returned. So if a model other than $rowId exists, you may proceed on deleted $rowId model.